# JS - Save whole number as float

Tags: javascript

I need to create a function that gets a number and return a float (not as string), how can I do it?

```
Function (num) {
    return num.toFloat()
}
```

Comment: there already is a function that does it `parseFloat(num)`

Comment: [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) can also help

Comment: to fixed makes a string, so you would have to combine it

Comment: well code is not valid and JavaScript has no real concept of float, so not sure what you are expecting. There is parseInt and parseFloat, but in the end it is just a number.... What is `num`? Why is your function written wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you please provide more information because your question is too broad

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript only has a single number type. Every number is already a floating point value, following the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

There is nothing you have to do.